# Html table in outlook template

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I want to insert a html table in an email template like this:

```
___________________________________________
|           |             |               |
|           |             |               |
|___________|             |_______________|
|           |             |               |
|           |             |               |
|___________|_____________|_______________|
```

I cant figure it out...

```
<h2>Cell that spans two columns:</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Could give you the code to make that table, however, would want to see what you have tried first.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: i have tried but i cant make it work ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the pre-existing rowspan and colspan from HTML, something like this perhaps?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 150px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <!-- Block 1 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
  <!-- Block 2 -->
  <td colspan="4" rowspan="6">Data Goes Here</td>
    <!-- Block 3 -->
    <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <!-- Block 1 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
  <!-- Block 2 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <!-- Block 1 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
  <!-- Block 2 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <!-- Block 1 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
  <!-- Block 2 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <!-- Block 1 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
  <!-- Block 2 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <!-- Block 1 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
  <!-- Block 2 -->
  <td colspan="4">Data Goes Here</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It is what I wanted.

Comment: No worries! If it is indeed what you wanted, please mark it as the answer so people see it's solved! :) @wittman